# Failed to send join request to master?

Tags: elasticsearch, docker

I'm a newer to `docker`,and i want to use `docker` to deploy `elasticsearch`.

I follow the document step by step.And i can start a `es` instance successful.such as `docker run -p 9208:9200  -p 9300:9300 -v /data/es1/elasticsearch.yml:/usr/share/elasticsearch/config/elasticsearch.yml docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:5.2.2`.

But when i want to add the node to a exist cluster,and add a config `discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts: ["xxx1:9300","xxx2:9300","xxx3:9300"]` in `/data/es1/elasticsearch.yml`,but it throws an exception:

```
failed to send join request to master [{es130-data}{FwWjvb52RzGRP2IRa15DeA}{owS9GmMXTAqn0kioUtGmtw}{xxx}{xxx:9301}{box_type=warm, master=false}], reason [RemoteTransportException[[es130-data][xxx:9301][internal:discovery/zen/join]]; nested: ConnectTransportException[[ddFr9ut][172.17.0.2:9300] connect_timeout[30s]]; nested: IOException[No route to host: 172.17.0.2/172.17.0.2:9300]; ]
```

Here are my all configs:

```
cluster.name: skynet
cluster.routing.allocation.same_shard.host: true
node.attr.box_type: warm
node.attr.master: true
node.data: true
discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts: ["xxx1:9300","xxx2:9300","xxx3:9300"]
network.host: [_site_,_local_]
```

Comment: Any updates onto this? were you able to solve it?